# When I run my app in android studio it runs a different app

Tags: android-studio

I have two different projects (for simplicity I will call them project 1 and project 2).
When I run project 1 it runs just fine. However when I run project 2 for some reason it runs project 1. How may I be able to fix this.

Comment: There is not enough information to help you troubleshoot, you will have to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions are :

**1.**  Reinstall the application or clear the cache from settings.

**2.**  Restart the emulator without saving its state.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow.